# Why does mathoverflow constantly compile the latex for my questions and answers?

Tags: support, mathjax, user-interface

Whenever I ask or answer questions on mathoverflow, the output is constantly being compiled. While this is sometimes a desirable feature, it turns out that at least for my computer, when I am giving a lengthy answer or asking a lengthy question, the latex slows down my computer very much (my computer does not get slowed down however when I give a shorter answer or ask a shorter question). Is there currently any way to turn this feature off while I simply type the answer since I do not need it to compile every second? Right now the most reasonable solution to this problem is to simply type my answer or question on a word document or onto a latex compiler and then use cut and paste.

Comment: There used to be a way to disable preview on the old MO 1.0 but that got lost in the transition. Consider making a feature request to bring it back. Have you tried [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/)? Is the slowdown the same there?

Comment: I have not experienced any significant slowdown on StackEdit.

Comment: Interesting, I've experienced the opposite problem lately: when an answer gets too long, MathJax apparently stops (pre-)compiling at some point.

Comment: Related: [How to turn off the MathJax preview?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/2660)

Answer (score 14):

I want to see how may people also have this problem or if I am the only one, so let me conduct a basic poll.

$\bullet$ If you have the problem where typing a long answer with plenty of mathematics symbols (an answer that fills at least one or two pages) on mathoverflow runs slowly, then upvote this answer.

$\bullet$ If you do not have any delays when typing long answers on mathoverflow, then downvote this answer.

Comment: I realize that this poll is probably very biased since the people experiencing this problem are more likely the click on this question.

Comment: I almost always compose my answers and questions in a separate editor, and then copy/paste into the MO field just before posting.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins: Me too. -- But I observed that after pasting, I need to make at least one change -- otherwise MO lets me solve a CAPTCHA, which can be annoying since sometimes the characters are also not very legible for a human.

Comment: I do not find that the formatting is slow, but it does create a very annoying kind of flicker.  I generally stretch the answer box so that the formatted answer is invisible below the bottom of the browser, which cures the problem for me.

Comment: I downvoted, but experience the same kind of "flicker" as Neil. I would describe it as a kind of "bouncing" of the characters as I type (and like him, I shield myself from having to look at it).

Answer (score 11):

My apologies if this should be a comment rather than answer, but [robjohn](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/13854/robjohn)  has a [website](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~robjohn/math/mathjax.html) with some very handy bookmarks to deal with these issues. Obviously it would be preferable if a bookmark bar were not needed, but `rendering on` and `rendering off` are quite helpful currently.